# CentOS: Unable to install Chromium browser

Tags: linux, centos, chromium, fedora

I am trying to install chromium in centOS 6.i run the following commands as root user.

cd /etc/yum.repos.d/

wget http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/spot/chromium/fedora-chromium-stable.repo .
but when i run command yum install chromium

its giving me error

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.vonline.vn
 * extras: mirrors.digipower.vn
 * updates: mirror.vietoss.com
http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/spot/chromium-stable/fedora-6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Setting up Install Process
No package chromium available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Please help in resolving it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

execute following commands (with root or sudoers privilege)

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d                                                   ##Moving to a certain directory
wget http://people.centos.org/hughesjr/chromium/6/chromium-el6.repo   ##Download the chromium package
yum install chromium                                                  ##Install the chromium packages in the mentioned directory
```

Comment: can u please help a little what is the most suitable method for installing softwares in fedora/centOS and from where get these url repos.please guide a little.

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta: I recommend to download packages from http://pkgs.org/ for your linux flavour,you can find most of packages there,just search package over there

Comment: i used your steps .its installed successfully.but after that when i run command chrome,chromium.its printing chromium is not a command.

Comment: You can find chromium in Applications->Internet->Chromium

Comment: run "chromium-browser" from terminal

Comment: On my old CentOS 6.2 I also had to "yum install -y gtk2 libX11" to get rid of "undefined symbol: gdk_screen_get_primary_monitor" and "undefined symbol: _XGetRequest".

Comment: I'm getting 404 error during yum chromium install with the link : http://install.linux.ncsu.edu/pub/yum/itecs/public/chromium/rhel6.7/repodata/repomd.xml which is truly 404. Any ideas what's wrong ?

Comment: Would you know how to do it for Centos 7?

Comment: The link is dead. Any chance of updating it, or posting the content of the file?

Answer (score 2):

Late answer and not the desired solution, but I've installed `Chrome` on **`CentOS 7`** using:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
```

Latest Google Chrome **no longer supports** **6.x.** You need CentOS **7.x**.

Answer (score 1):

https://discuss.tutorialdba.com/852/install-epel-repository-centos explains how to install Chromium on CentOS 8, should you need to.

If

`sudo dnf --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="epel" list available | grep chromium`

confirms you've got epel installed and chromium is available, then run

`sudo dnf --enablerepo="epel" install chromium`

to perform the install successfully.