# Unable to install chromium in my centOS7

Tags: centos, chromium

I have this [Unable to install chromium in my centOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623131/unable-to-install-chromium-in-my-centos) problem in Centos7. Suggested solution does not work in 7. It's missing libude.so dependency.

Answer (score 4):

After some try and error I came to simple solution as simple as:

```
yum install epel-release
yum install chromium
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add the third yum to your yum repository under the file yum.repos.d,such as epel ,rpmforge.and then goto terminal with command:
  yum -y install chromium.x86_64
once compelete,a chromuim browser will display on your application manager,you can click it to open on your Desktop.
also you can use the command chromium-browser on terminal.